# Shutdown instead of sleep

Tags: windows, sleep, shutdown

I need my windows 10 PC to shutdown any time it wants to go into sleep mode.

For whatever reason, instead of sleeping it should (force) shutdown instead.

How should I proceed?

Comment: you can change the power settings to shutdown instead of sleep after specific amounts of time/when you press the power button, etc

Answer (score 0):

You should probably elaborate on what you're trying to solve.

Assuming you really want your PC to shutdown after a period of inactivity, I guess you could create a scheduled task, triggered by inactivity, and make it run `shutdown /s /f`.

Comment: Not only that, I have a program that makes your computer sleep after a while you stopped watching a fullscreen video, be it on vlc player or on your browser. There's no option to make it shutdown instead.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/sleepsharp/files/

Comment: I think [MPC-HC](https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc) can shutdown your computer when it's finished playing a video file.